# How can I make gridview cells be textboxes instead of labels?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

My gridview is supposed to display data from an Excel datasheet. I am able to display the data in the grid but only as labels with the Excel values. I'm trying to make it an editable gridview and hence keep in in edit mode which is why I need the cells to be textboxes. How can I do that?

[Visual Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4Nu0.png)

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView4" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
            GridLines="None" OnRowCommand="GridView4_RowCommand" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView4_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton OnClick="UpdateRow_Click" 
                            ID="LinkButton1" 
                            runat="server" 
                            CausesValidation="false" 
                            CommandName="Update" 
                            Text="Update">
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add more `ItemTemplate` with textboxes in it, set textboxes value with your columns name. and dont forget to set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false`.

```
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton OnClick="UpdateRow_Click" 
                        ID="LinkButton1" 
                        runat="server" 
                        CausesValidation="false" 
                        CommandName="Update" 
                        Text="Update">
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox 
                        ID="textBox1" 
                        runat="server" 
                        Text='<%#Eval("Column1")>'>
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox 
                        ID="textBox2" 
                        runat="server" 
                        Text='<%#Eval("Column2")%>'>
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox 
                        ID="textBox3" 
                        runat="server" 
                        Text='<%#Eval("Column3")%>'>
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
```

Comment: That did not work, my gridview no longer displays the information from the Excel sheet :/
It now only displays one column that has textboxes with <%Eval("Mobile") %> in it. Even the Upload button is gone

Comment: The gridview is now only displaying the last column of the Excel sheet table. Even when I'm viewing the design of the gridview it only shows one column with databound textboxes and still no update button.

Comment: You are a boss my friend, thank you for your time :)